# Подскажите в чем может быть проблема при парсинге json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый вечер. Имею JSON

```
[
{
"icon": "images/status/icon01.jpg",
"ticket": "001",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "23.12.15",
"update": "27.12.15",
"deadline": "31.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon02.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "17.12.15",
"update": "22.12.15",
"deadline": "7.01.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon03.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "04.12.15",
"update": "---",
"deadline": "15.02.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon04.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "29.11.15",
"update": "15.12.15",
"deadline": "25.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon01.jpg",
"ticket": "001",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "23.12.15",
"update": "27.12.15",
"deadline": "31.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon02.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "17.12.15",
"update": "22.12.15",
"deadline": "7.01.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon03.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "04.12.15",
"update": "---",
"deadline": "15.02.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon04.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "29.11.15",
"update": "15.12.15",
"deadline": "25.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon01.jpg",
"ticket": "001",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "23.12.15",
"update": "27.12.15",
"deadline": "31.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon02.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "17.12.15",
"update": "22.12.15",
"deadline": "7.01.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon03.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "04.12.15",
"update": "---",
"deadline": "15.02.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon04.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "29.11.15",
"update": "15.12.15",
"deadline": "25.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon01.jpg",
"ticket": "001",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "23.12.15",
"update": "27.12.15",
"deadline": "31.12.15"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon02.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "17.12.15",
"update": "22.12.15",
"deadline": "7.01.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon03.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Вывести счетчик компаний и договоров.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "04.12.15",
"update": "---",
"deadline": "15.02.16"
},
{
"icon": "images/status/icon04.jpg",
"ticket": "002",
"title": "Оптимизировать Kaod getProducts.",
"p": "__",
"status": "Открыто",
"solution": "Решение",
"create": "29.11.15",
"update": "15.12.15",
"deadline": "25.12.15"
}
]
```

не выводит данные в chromium, хотя на firefox выпводит, но ругается.

- Это ошибка chromium 
  jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/user/Documents/jquery_test/data_1.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

-Это ошибка firefox
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: file:///home/user/Documents/jquery_test/data.json
Line Number 1, Column 1:

делаю на jQuery

код следующий

```
  var getTasksList = function (url, showTasks) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET',

        success: function (data) {
            showTasks(data);
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Вы делаете запрос к локальным файлам - это небезопасно, фаерфокс пазрешает такое "из коробки", в хроме же надо отключить web security в настройках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Эта ошибка означает, что браузер блокирует кросс-доменные запросы. Кросс-доменные запросы - это запросы, имеющие разные домены, т.е. в вашем случае:
  Ваш домен, например - localhost/

Запрос уходит с домена "localhost/" на "file:///home/user/Documents/jquery_test/data_1.json"

Браузер видит, что запрос ушел на не тот же домен (т.е. не на адрес localhost/.../data_1.json, а на адрес file:///home/.../data_1.json) и интерпретирует это, как кросс-доменный запрос.

В общем запросы должны уходить по адресу "localhost/jquery_test/data_1.json" в этом случае (ну или любой другой путь, но путь этот должен содержать ваш домен, с которого уходит запрос, т.е. если проще, то положите json-файл в папку с вашим скриптом и обращайтесь по пути этого файла)

Еще здесь можно почитать о кросс-доменных запросах
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, и предоставленную статью!